# Error: dataset root directory does not exist

Tags: artificial-intelligence, generative-adversarial-network

I am training stylegan2 on google cloud jupyter notebook.

```
!python run_training.py --num-gpus=4 --data-dir=~/datasets --config=config-f \ --dataset=bladerunner --mirror-augment=true
```

and getting this error:

> Error: dataset root directory does not exist.

It's strange as I have already used the datasets folder to convert images to tfrecords successfully.

Answer (score 0):

changed to direct address

```
--data-dir=/home/shahik/datasets
```